Compilation error for multidimensional lists
Dear Mathematica users,
I have a code as:
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
$CCompiler = {"Compiler" -> CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`GenericCCompiler,"CompilerInstallation" -> "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin", "CompilerName" -> "gcc.exe"};

beamnenz = {{2}, {3}};

cf2 = Compile[{{NBeamPatch, _Integer, 0}, {beamnenz, _Integer, 2}},

Block[

Datildaezintke = ConstantArray[0., {1, NBeamPatch}];

Do[

Datildaezintke[[1, i]] = ConstantArray[0., {5*beamnenz[[i, 1]], 5*beamnenz[[i, 1]]}];

, {i, 1, NBeamPatch}

];

Datildaezintke

];

calling the compiled function, cf2 below as:
cf2[2, beamnenz]

results in errors as:
CompiledFunction::cfte: Compiled expression {{{{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.},{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.},{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.},{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.},{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.},{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.},{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.},{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.},{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.},{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.}},0.}} should be a rank 2 tensor of machine-size real numbers. >>
CompiledFunction::cfexe: Could not complete external evaluation; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>
How could we fix this problem? Datildaezintke matrix must be a jagged array which means its dimensions are as:
Datildaezintke[[1, 1, 5*2, 5*2]] and

Datildaezintke[[1, 2, 5*3, 5*3]]

If we edit the above problem with a simpler one by omitting jagged arrays as:
NBeamPatch=1;

cf2 = Compile[{{NBeamPatch, _Integer, 0}},

Block[

{Datildaezintke},

Datildaezintke = ConstantArray[0., {1, NBeamPatch, 2}];

Dimensions[Datildaezintke]

]

, CompilationTarget -> "C"

];

and when calling the compiled function as:
cf2[1]

results in
CompiledFunction::cfte: Compiled expression {{{0.,0.}}} should be a rank 2 tensor of machine-size real numbers. >>
CompiledFunction::cfexe: Could not complete external evaluation; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>
Can we define a constant array with 3 dimensions or more while compiling? It is permitted while uncompiled mode in Mathematica.
I appreciate for your helps.
Best wishes,
Ahmet

“Datildaezintke matrix must be a jagged array” Since you mention this, you're aware of that limitation, right?

Is there any particular reason you are compiling your code, which is in essence quite simple, and should already be very fast without compilation? Since you seem to be a beginner in Mathematica, I strongly suggest you first learn and use Mathematica without compiling.

I just try to explain my problem in a simple case, Domen. Surely, the case is more complex and executing takes so much time.

@xzczd, I'm not aware of the limitation. Can't we compile jagged arrays?

Yes, see e.g. 6th rule in this post, and this post that circumvent the issue for a special case.

@xzczd, ConstantArray can be compiled, I have tried it and seen that it can only take 2-dimensional arrays not more, unfortunately.

No: https://i.sstatic.net/LRoiGjdr.png Once again, please read the linked post.
